# Problems about open .ipynb file incorrectly in PycharmI

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

[*I want use jupyter notebook in Pycharm,but when I open .ipynb file,it show as I show*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsoMN.png)

Comment: Do you have PyCharm professional? Jupyter notebook support appears to be only available in PyCharm professional: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html

Comment: oh,I found that the FileTypes in Preferences,the .ipynb file is will be opened by Text.